# I need to get the result as per following details in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]

I have two different tables of same columns. One is #temp1 and another is #temp2.

The attached images contains the dataset for each table.

I have write a query to get the data. Here is the query:

```
SELECT distinct A.EmpID, A.DeptIdID, A.RoomID,
    IN= CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(S, A.IN, B.IN) >= 0 THEN B.IN ELSE A.In END,
    Out= CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(S, A.Out, B.Out) >= 0 THEN A.Out ELSE B.Out END

FROM #temp1 A
INNER JOIN #temp2 B
ON (A.In>= B.In AND A.In< B.In)
    OR (A.Out> B.OutAND A.Out<= B.Out)
```

What I want is to get the data from #temp1 whose In and out belongs between the In and Out of the #temp2. The above query works quite well for absolute in and out entry.

Consider the Entry No 11 of #temp1 and Entry No 1 and 4 of #temp2.
In and Out entry of #temp1 is from 17 Apr -20 Apr, while there are two entry for this date range in #temp2. One is from 12 Apr-18 Apr and another one is from 18 Apr- 20    Apr. Thus the Result from #temp1 should split in two following entries.

1. 17 Apr- 18 Apr with RoomId=1 from the column value of #temp2.
2. 18 Apr- 20 Apr with RoomId=2 from the column value of #temp2.

and there should be only unique column for #temp1.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Your examples are quite limited. What should happen for example if there's several smaller ranges inside a one big range in the other table? Your data should be as text / insert clauses / in sql fiddle if someone really wants to help you, instead of having to write your data from a picture.

Comment: Could be an interesting problem, but it is not clear what you want to achieve or what the data means. I assume empid is unique. Is room uniquely defined by deptid  + roomid? Do the two tables represent rooms in two departments deptid = 1 and 0 and who booked them and the booking dates they used? Looks like the JOIN condition won't return any rows as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question but it looks as if you want to find any employees who have booked/used different rooms at overlapping dates. If you concatenate `#temp1` and `#temp2` into one table `#rooms`, you can run this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #rooms A
INNER JOIN #rooms B on a.empid = b.empid 
    and a.deptid * 10000 + a.roomid < b.deptid * 10000 + b.roomid
where (A.indt <= B.outdt and A.outdt >= B.indt)
```

I'm assuming the room is identified by `deptid & roomid`. I'm using a quick and dirty hack to produce a single integer that uniquely identifies the combination of `deptid` and `roomid`, assuming `roomid` is always less than `10000`.

If `roomid` uniquely identifies the room, use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #rooms A
INNER JOIN #rooms B on a.empid = b.empid 
    and a.roomid < b.roomid
where (A.indt <= B.outdt and A.outdt >= B.indt)
```

The `a.roomid < b.roomid` trick eliminates duplicates. If you said `a.roomid <> b.roomid` the same overlap would be reported twice, once from A's point of view and again from B's point of view.

I'm also assuming `empid` uniquely identifies the employee. The employee id tends to be company wide because employees can move between departments.

HTH. It was an interesting question, please post back if you wanted something different.

Comment: I appreciate your effort and contribution. There are extra load of 10000 which will not work for me as there are trillions of records in each table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right this will help:

```
SELECT  a.EmpId,
        a.DeptId,
        a.RoomId,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.EmpId ORDER BY a.[In]) = 1 THEN a.[In] ELSE b.[In] END as [In],
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.EmpId ORDER BY a.[In]) = 2 THEN a.[Out] ELSE b.[In] END as [Out]
FROM #temp1 a
INNER JOIN #temp2 b
    ON b.[In] between a.[In] and a.[Out] and b.[Out] between a.[In] and a.[Out]
```

Output:

```
EmpId       DeptId      RoomId      In         Out
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
7637        1           1           2016-04-17 2016-04-18
7637        1           1           2016-04-18 2016-04-20
7638        1           1           2016-04-15 2016-04-18
7638        1           1           2016-04-18 2016-04-20
7639        1           1           2016-04-17 2016-04-18
7639        1           1           2016-04-18 2016-04-20
```

But if there is more then 2 rows in `#temp2` for 1 row in `#temp1` that wouldn't work for you.

Comment: I appreciate your effort and contribution. But this will not work for me as there are multiple rows in #temp2 for 1 rows in #temp1 and vice versa is also there.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the answers and I appreciate the effort of each contributors of the Stack Overflow developer Community.

I applied both of the methods mentioned above but did not work in my case.

I was working on this query from the last week and finally got what I want.
Here it is what I have did.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.EmpID, A.In, A.Out) AS RowID,
    A.EmpID,
    IN= CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(S, A.In, B.In) >= 0 THEN B.In ELSE A.In END,
    Out= CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(S, A.Out, B.Out) >= 0 THEN A.Out ELSE B.Out END,
    CASE WHEN B.DeptID=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsAuthorized,
    CASE WHEN (((A.In>= B.In AND A.In <= B.Out)) AND B.DeptID=1 AND A.DeptId=1)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsAccessed

    FROM #temp1 A
    INNER JOIN #temp2 B
    ON A.EmpID=B.EmpID 
    AND ((A.In>= B.In AND A.In < B.Out)
            OR (A.Out > B.In AND A.Out <= B.Out))
    ORDER BY A.EmpID
```

Once again I appreciate your effort.

Happy Coding :)

Thank You !

Avtansh